# After 10 items in my listview, one of the text views does not display

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I have a android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2 list view which uses the code below, when I add in 10 items into the listview everything works fine, and then when I add another item the first line of the list is not displayed, (although the ontextlistener says that it is there) this happens for every single one beyond the 10th item in the list.

this is the code that adds the items to the list

```
meetingList.add(new String[] {db.get(0).getDate(), " "});
        meetingList.add(new String[] {db.get(0).getName(), db.get(0).getEvent() });

for (int i = 1; i<db.size(); i++){          
                if (db.get(i).getDate() != database.list.get(i-1).getDate()){
                    meetingList.add(new String[] {db.get(i).getDate(), " "});
                }           
            meetingList.add(new String[] { database.list.get(i).getName(), database.list.get(i).getEvent() });          
        }
```

this is my list adapter

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String[]>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, meetingList) {     

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


                // Must always return just a View.
                final View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                // If you look at the android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2 source, you'll see
                // it's a TwoLineListItem with 2 TextViews - text1 and text2.
                // TwoLineListItem listItem = (TwoLineListItem) view;

                final String[] entry = meetingList.get(position);
                TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);                                        
                TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);

                text1.setText(entry[0]);
                text2.setText(entry[1]);
                if (entry[1].equals(" ")){
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#009ACD"));
                text1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                text1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                text1.setTextSize(22);               

                }
                else {
                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    text1.setTextSize(25);
                    text2.setTextSize(18);
                }

                final Context context = getApplicationContext();
                final int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                text1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {  
                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, entry[0], duration);
                        toast.show();                       
                    }
                });
```

Comment: since ListView is reusing items `1` and `2` in `if (entry[1].equals(" ")){ /*1*/ } else { /*2*/ }` should do exact oposite things ... fx.: in your code you set color of `text1` in `1` but do not reverse it in `2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That getView() method looks messy.

Create a View (like a `LinearLayout`) that has those 2 TextViews, in xml:

```
<com.example.myApp.view.MyListView
  ...>
   <TextView android:id="@+id/txt1
      ...>
   <TextView android:id="@+id/txt2
      ...>

<com.example.myApp.view.MyListView />
```

Then create a Class in package

> com.example.myApp.view

(or whatever you want to call it) that's called `MyListView` and `extends LinearLayout` (or Relative, etc..)

then in your getView method:

- check if convertView != null

if so, `MyListView listview = (MyListView) convertView`

else, `MyListView listview = new MyListView()`

then add methods to MyListView to set TextViews etc.

and then `return listview`